# select_related on many to many with custom through table

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, Foo and Bar, and I have created a many to many relationship with a custom through table, FooBar.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foofield = models.CharField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    barfield = models.CharField()
    foos = models.ManyToManyField('Foo', through='FooBar', related_name='foo_bar')

class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='foobar')
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name='foobar')
    foobarfield= models.CharField()
```

What I would like to do is display all Bar records for a given instance of Foo, and for each such record also display the corresponding value of foobarfield. So I would get something like

1. barfield_value1, foobarfield_value1
2. barfield_value2, foobarfield_value2
3. barfield_value3, foobarfield_value3
4. ...

I can't seem to construct the correct query to do this though. I tried something like

```
Bar.objects.select_related('foobar').filter(foobar__foo = foo_instance)
```

Since I would expect foobar to be unique for a give instance of Foo but this does not seem to work. How do I get the result I want?

Comment: You need doublee underscores, so `foobar__foo=foo_instance`.

Comment: Furthermore you will need to annotate, or filter on a *prefetch*.

Comment: ok, and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: How would foobar be unique for a given instance of Foo? Foo and Bar are related via a ManytoManyRelationship (FooBar). So for a given instance of Foo, you might have multiple instances of Bar in the FooBar Table.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will have one result for every related row in the `FooBar` table, and since you want to access fields on that table (`foobarfield`), the most straightforward approach is to filter on `FooBar`:

```
foobars = FooBar.objects.select_related("bar").filter(foo=foo_instance)
for foobar in foobars:
    print(foobar.bar.barfield, foobar.foobarfield)
```